# Как получить информацию об отправленной фотке? telebot

Tags: python, telebot

Есть данный код(по нажатию кнопки), не могу понять как осуществить получение информации, об отправленном фото.(Например название фотки с сервера/компьютера)

```
    if message.text == 'Коты':
        photo = open('cats/' + random.choice(os.listdir('cats')), 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sended_message = bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, photo)
print(sended_message) # Вернёт объект message
```

Comment: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: file must be non-empty", с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Говорит что вы отправляете пустой файл

Comment: но я не могу отправлять пустой файл =(

Comment: Попробуйте заменить:

photo = open(os.path.join('cats', random.choice(os.listdir('cats'))), 'rb')

Comment: ничего не поменялось(